# List private repositories of bitbucket using api 2.0

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am writing a bash script which will take a backup of my all bitbucket cloud repositories.

I have multiple private repositories in bitbucket and I want to list them using Bitbucket API 2.0

I have tried adding Bitbucket consumer but I am stuck at how to create an access token and used in curl command which gives me a list of all private repositories

Can someone please let me know about Auth generation in Bitbucket and How to generate an access token and pass it to bitbucket API?